# elixir - how to get all elements except last in the list?

Tags: elixir

Let say I have a list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

How can I get all elements from this list except last? So, I'll have `[1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My solution (I think it's not a clean, but it works!)

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
[head | tail] = Enum.reverse(a)
Enum.reverse(tail) # [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: It may not be intuitive, but based on a quick test, it is the most effective. https://gist.github.com/ckhrysze/015a8748910c8d467bd2a6e2c832a670
## PopBench
reverse      500000   6.64 µs/op
drop         500000   6.73 µs/op
take         100000   26.07 µs/op

Comment: Actually this is a very common pattern in many of the implementations of the Enum functions. There is an optimized :list.reverse in Erlang that is used after a reduction gives you the list you want but in the reverse of the order you want it.

Answer (score 39):

Use Enum.drop/2 like this:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
Enum.drop list, -1      # [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking to get both the last item and the rest of the list preceding it you can now use `List.pop_at/3`:

```
{last, rest} = List.pop_at([1, 2, 3], -1)
{3, [1, 2]}
```

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#pop_at/3

Answer (score 2):

Another option besides the `list |> Enum.reverse |> tl |> Enum.reverse` mentioned before is Erlang's [`:lists.droplast`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/lists.erl#L215) function which is slower according to the documentation but creates less garbage because it doesn't create two new lists. Depending on your use case that might be an interesting one to use.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, though not elegant, would be -

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
Enum.take(list, Enum.count(list) -1 )   # [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Erlang

```
List = [1,2,3,4,5],
NewList = DropLast(List).

DropLast(List) while length(List) > 0 and is_list(List) ->
    {NewList, _} = lists:split(OldList, length(OldList)-1),
    NewList.
```